# tcpdump -i any and slave interfaces

Tags: tcpdump

The core requirement can be expressed as "filtering out slave interfaces from -i any".

In this case, packets leaving on a vlan for bond0 should not also be retrieved for bond0, or the underlying physical interfaces, and in the case of ppp interfaces, we don't want to see the traffic again on the ifb interface either.

Details of the (rather complicated) configuration:

- bond0 running in 802.3ad with slaves enp1s0f1 and enp1s0f1 (2 x 10Gbps).
- multiple VLANs involved on top of that (enough to be problematic).  Double-tagged in some cases.
- pppoe server on around 50 of those.
- Other VLANs just have normal IP/nets assigned.
- active pppoe + pppol2tp connections (~200).
- Most ppp interfaces have a related ifb-ppp interface for ingress shaping using tc (which requires mirred action).

Basic tcpdump command currently:

```
tcpdump -vnei any -s0 port 53 and host $loopback_ip
```

Using "ether proto 0x0800" does NOT work.  This would have been almost ideal since on the physicals and bond0 the ethertype for 802.11q really is not 0x0800 but rather 0x8100 (but the nested type remains 0x0800 which is why, I suspect, tcpdump or bpf in general returns the frame here) .

The idea is to capture a single copy of every DNS packet entering or leaving the local system (not those which is just routing through).

Output looks something like (for a single packet coming in off a ppp link to the local node, and response going back out again):

```
12:33:43.996592 ppp155 In  ifindex 1428484 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 80: (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 14910, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 60)
    a.b.c.d.54070 > e.f.g.h.53: 38860+ A? www.google.com. (32)
12:33:43.996598 ifb-ppp155 Out ifindex 1428485 00:00:3f:11:16:20 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 80: (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 14910, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 60)
    a.b.c.d.54070 > e.f.g.h.53: 38860+ A? www.google.com. (32)
    enter code here

12:33:43.996649 ppp155 Out ifindex 1428484 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 96: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18785, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    e.f.g.h.53 > a.b.c.d.54070: 38860 1/0/0 www.google.com. A 216.58.223.132 (48)
```

Here is problem one.  We use ifb devices to along with tc shape ingress traffic.  Yes, we really do shape here not just police.  So we see the frame twice.  We don't care for the duplicate on ifb-ppp155.

The response is only given once, but seeing that tc doesn't "redirect" the traffic, this is expected.  Since the traffic is then pppoe encapsulated, the filter also filters out the pppoe frame going out on the relevant vlan to bond0 to either the underlying interfaces (similar for incoming).

The problem when traffic is on raw VLANs is easiest to illustrate with a query LEAVING the host outbound to a remote server:

```
12:38:55.396412 bond0.2 Out ifindex 7 00:11:0a:69:8f:b0 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 80: (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 3629, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 60)
    a.b.c.d.36796 > e.f.g.h.53: 21853+ A? www.google.com. (32)
12:38:55.396413 bond0 Out ifindex 6 00:11:81:00:00:02 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 84: IP8 (invalid)
12:38:55.396414 enp1s0f0 Out ifindex 2 00:11:81:00:00:02 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 84: IP8 (invalid)

12:38:55.396476 enp1s0f1 In  ifindex 3 48:df:81:00:00:02 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: IP15 (invalid)
12:38:55.396476 bond0 In  ifindex 6 48:df:81:00:00:02 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: IP15 (invalid)
12:38:55.396476 bond0.2 In  ifindex 7 48:df:37:3d:f5:c4 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 96: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47664, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    e.f.g.h.53 > a.b.c.d.36796: 21853 1/0/0 www.google.com. A 172.217.170.100 (48)
```

Extra newline added for emphasis.  These "six" packets really are just two.  I don't want those that gives "(invalid)" being output, ideally they should not pass the bpf filter such that they aren't duplicated from the kernel to userspace three times, but just once.

As it stands the amount of traffic we're capturing on just bond0.2 is insufficient to gather information of DNS based attacks (in particular a large outage that's making headlines today relates), and expanding the filter to -i any causes in too much traffic to be captured, and it ends up confusing the matter.  We suspect that one or more client routers are performing specially crafted lookups that then results in bad stuff happening.  We are blocking inbound DNS queries at the network edge not destined to known DNS authoritative hosts.

The ONLY other possibility I can think of right now is to actually use iptables's NFLOG to send the related INPUT and OUTPUT frames to a purpose-built user-space application, and this may end up being the way to go, but I reckon if we can just use tcpdump to gather the raw data then we should be able to use wireshark or similar to track down the attack vector.  And should be faster than building purpose-built applications.

Comment: I seem to recall there being an answer to this on ServerFault, although I think the answer might have been that it isn't possible to do with a single tcpdump instance.

Comment: This has pretty much been my finding as well.